# When do Firebase Analytics count a user as active?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I have an app where users need to sign-up in order to use it. The signup process can take up to a minute or so and eventually, it could fail, so the user doesn’t actually use the app.

My question is, how can I make Firebase count a user active, only after he/she has verified his/her account, so I can have proper retention analytics?

Answer (score 0):

you can have a login page that when accessed triggers your analytics to report that a user has accessed the page in question, this way, you are able to track both app instances and logged-in users.

You can find the list of events and parameters here:

- https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7061705?hl=en

Comment: This way though I won't be able to get the retention

Comment: Analytics is only there so you can track your App's behavior, not your users. for that, you will want to look at BigQuery. - https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics#integrations_with_other_services